# SD card reader with detachable cord and SD card fitting inside

Tags: usb, sd-card

mandatory:

1. full-sized SD card does not stick out of card readers' case
2. detachable cable (connected to card reader via micro-USB A or USC C, mini-USB B may also be acceptable)
3. matte case without glossy parts

preferable:

1. black color (or other dark color)
2. sturdy case (metal or hard plastic)

does not matter:

1. price
2. brand
3. whether any extra functions make it bigger (unless it is bigger than 230W power brick from gaming notebook) **EDIT: now want it to be smaller than Sony MRWE90/BC1 XQD**

for example, HDD enclosures listed below would fit the bill if they would accept SD cards instead of (or in addition to) 2.5" drives

https://www.inateck.com/inateck-fe2004-usb-3-0-hdd-external-enclosure.html

https://www.inateck.com/hard-drive-accessories/hdd-enclosures/tool-free-usb-3-0-hdd-enclosure/inateck-usb-3-0-2-5-portable-hdd-enclosure-3port-usb-3-0-hub.html

any suggestions for where to look for it?

Answer (score 0):

Sony MRWE90/BC1 XQD seems to fit all my requirements (yet to buy it to find out for sure), although it is almost as big as 2.5" HDD enclosure and costs over $50 (former drawback is more important for me)

so my search continues with added criteria: 
smaller than Sony MRWE90/BC1 XQD and without XQD slot, or with USB type C connector, or docking station / port replicator that has full-sized SD slot

EDIT: yes, it does, except second slot for sony's proprietary XQD memory cards is useless for me until XQD to SD adapter is created